# JavaScript double-space match works local but not live?

Tags: javascript

For some unfathomable reason I can reliably detect double spaces in text `input` elements on localhost but *not* on live sites with *everything* verified (deleted/upload files, browsing with cache disabled, manually verifying the script file is updated, testing in the console, etc).

My original code:

```
if (document.getElementById('example').value.indexOf('  ')!='-1') {}
```

My second attempt:

```
if (document.getElementById('example').value.split('  ').length>1)
```

I'm completely baffled, the script works fine in Firefox and Chrome locally though not live and I am absolutely 100% certain that everything on the server has been updated. I've even run the validation with the script commented out just to make certain.

Comment: Have you checked there aren't errors (ie check the console) on the live site? Can you provide a demo where the problem exists?

Comment: Another thing you can try is to map the live site to your local environment by editing the hosts file. If there are any cross-domain scripting issues, that will allow you to debug them.

Comment: Nope, no cross-domain issues and definitely no console errors as I mentioned I've tested the script from the console.

Comment: Did you try to search for _&nbsp;&nbsp;_ ?

Comment: You're probably better off using a regular expression i.e. txt = document.getElementById('example').value; txt = txt.replace(/ {2,}/gm, ' ');

Comment: @jeff Please edit or delete your comment, the **replace** word I *explicitly* searched Google for with `-replace` operator. I'll edit mine. Posting my working answer now. Thanks!

Comment: CHeck out this linf for the STRING replace method : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @jeff *Please read my previous comment and remove the word 'replace' from your comment!* Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! So I don't know what the heck was wrong with the other code...it worked fine on localhost and I'm at a complete loss about that issue however I did some more poking around and determined that I can detect double spaces in JavaScript using the following:

```
if (document.getElementById('example').value.match(/\s{2,}/)!=null)
```